# linqtoxml - insert string literal into xml file

Tags: html, xml, linq-to-xml

I am using LINQ-to-XML. I am building a small program that helps parse HTML. I'd like to save the HTML tags into an XML file, but I don't want the XML file to check the validity of the entered HTML elements.

How can I just entere a simple string literal (a pretty long one)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe using a CDATA construct could help you out, see [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp)